# Prevent GIMP from raising & activating new windows/tabs

Tags: x11, gimp

I'm using XSane to scan images in to GIMP 2.8.16. With the scan settings, this unfortunately takes a few minutes per scan. I'm using GIMP's tabbed window mode.

It's nice that I can work on other things while it's scanning (including in GIMP). But, whenever a scan finishes, GIMP not only activates that new tab (including even if I'm in the middle of rotating or cropping a different image), but if GIMP is not the foreground window, it raises itself. If it's iconified, it uniconifies itself. If it's on a different desktop, it switches me to it's desktop.

I've searched its Preferences and couldn't find anything—is there a way to make GIMP load new images into a background tab and, even more importantly, not interrupt what I'm doing in other apps?

Comment: Does the solution have to be window-manager-independent or have to work with barebones window managers? Window managers control how windows appear and user-friendly window managers (e.g. not Gnome) allow the user to control this.

Comment: @Gilles I'm using e16 currently, but desperately need to upgrade... probability to KDE's kwin, which I use everywhere else. Not sure if it's focus stealing prevention would help. (Of course, won't help with the tab part). Recompiling GIMP seems easier than switching window managers, though.

Comment: Looks like I could comment out [`gimp_display_shell_present (shell)` in `gimp_display_new` from `app/display/gimpdisplay.c`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/app/display/gimpdisplay.c#n462) ... haven't tested this yet.

Comment: You could file this as a bug (or feature request) in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GIMP